# p:ajax not working inside p:outputPanel

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am trying to call a listener inside  using p:ajax. I am getting this error when i do it -  Unable to attach  to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent

Tried the same with  too and I am getting the same error. I think it is the problem with  My piece of code is this.

```
<p:columns rendered="#{someColumns.isColumnVisible(propName)}"
        sortBy="#{propName}" style="padding: 0px;"
        sortFunction="#{dataNav.sortOrders[propName]}">
<p:outputPanel id="#{propName}Cell" layout="block"
            style="width: 100%; 
        height: 100%; padding: 4px; margin: 0; cursor: pointer;" autoUpdate="true">
            <!-- <ui:insert /> -->
            <p:ajax event="click" global="true" immediate="true"
                listener="#{selectedRowHandler.setSelectedRowKey(rowKey)}"
                process="@this" update="#{tableId} #{render}" disabled="#{disabled}" />
            <p:ajax event="click" global="true"
                listener="#{selectedRowHandler.setSelectedRowKeyOnDblClick(rowKey)}"
                process="@this" update="#{tableId} #{render}" disabled="#{disabled}" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:columns>
```

I am using primefaces 6.1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955543/pajax-unable-to-attach-pajax-to-non-clientbehaviorholder-parent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<p:ajax> Unable to attach <p:ajax> to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955543/pajax-unable-to-attach-pajax-to-non-clientbehaviorholder-parent)